# List instances that do not have a specific label in GCP using python

Tags: python, google-compute-engine, google-compute-api

Is it possible to filter out instances on a wildcard or regex? I essentially just want GCE instances, not GKE or instances provisioned by other services.

I've found that GCP service created instances have a label attached that typically starts with `goog-*`. From GCP Cloud Logging I can filter these out fine but there's doesn't seem to be any support for regex in the python client.

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build

service = build('compute', 'v1', credentials=credentials)
request = service.instances().aggregatedList(project="my-project", filter="labels != goog-*")
```

Answer (score 1):

While it's not a documented feature that you get those `goog-something` labels when deploying a new cluster or even a single VM solution - in most cases it will be true.

To get get a nice list of all instances with labels other than `goog-` run:

```
gcloud compute instances list --filter=-labels:'goog-*'
```

Applying it to Python it can look like this:

```py
import os
os.system('gcloud compute instances list --filter=-labels:"goog-*"')
```

or you can use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run) (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/89243/12257250)).

If in any doubt you can have a look at the [`gcloud compute instances list` docs](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/list) and [how to use a filter option](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/topic/filters).

Comment: Appreciate the answer, unfortunately I'm looking to use python for this case. The `filter` parameter appears to follow a different convention than `gcloud` or the console. I ended up just listing all the instances and then manually filtering them out with python.

Comment: Tahnks for reply. I updated my answer with the python code.